# Parse does not let me create 4 rows of information for same user sign up

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am creating a Sign Up Table on Swift using Parse to store data. Users can select maximum of 4 activities from the given list of activities.

I want the table to store all the 4 records of selected separately. But the code only makes one record!

Here is the code snippet-

```
//Creating a NSMutableSet to avoid multiple selection of same sport.
var tempSport = NSMutableSet()
//The vales in tempSport are : ["Activity1", "Activity2", "Activity3", "Activity4"]


@IBAction func getStartedButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if tempSport.count < 1
    {
        //Display Alert
    }

    else
    {

        var sendSport = Array(tempSport.allObjects)

        print(sendSport)

            for sport in sendSport
            {   
                SportList["SportPlayer"] = user.username

                SportList["SportPlaying"] = String(sport)

                SportList.saveInBackground()
            }

    }

}
```

[Image Link. Click here to see the expected output and output produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKjV9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just save the object with an Array instead of 4 individual objects

```
let object = PFObject(className: "Your Class Name"
object["Sport Playing"] = [activity1, activity2, activity3, activity4]
object.saveInBackground()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to create a up to four sport objects for each user? That could end up becoming a lot of data in your database. I would recommend creating a a list of sports in the Parse database (soccer, football, tennis, etc) and create an array of users for each sport. For example, you would have Soccer under SportPlaying and an array of user objectIds under SportPlayer. Lets say you have a user with an objectId of H67c0uTUO1 that says they play Soccer, Basketball, and Lacrosse. You could send this data up to Parse by querying for the name of each sport that the user plays and adding the user's objectId to to the array using `.addObject`. Then, if you want a list of users who play that certain sport, you would query for using:

```
let sportQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")

sportQuery.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: yourArrayFromSportPlayerForSpecificSport as! [anyObject])

let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([sportQuery])

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError) -> Void in {


}
```